# How can I unwrap properly an Elasticsearch bulk response?

Tags: java, exception, elasticsearch

I'm using the following code:

```
BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
// ...
BulkResponse response = bulkRequest.execute().get();
if (response.hasFailures()) {
   String failureMessage = response.buildFailureMessage();
   // TODO
}
```

What is the best way to properly extract failureMessage?

If possible, I would like to avoid a test like this :

```
if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(failureMessage, "some text here"))
```

Actually, failureMessage contains a description about an Elasticsearch exception. Any wrapper to get it ?

Thanks to share your suggestions.